# Webpack not serving css file

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I am fairly new to webpack 4 and struggling to get my head around why I can not serve my css files.
I essentially start my dev server using 
`npm start`
I can then serve my javascript using 
`http://localhost:9000/js/app.bundle.js`
but when i try doing the same for my css file it gives a 404 
`http://localhost:9000/css/app.css`

My complete config is

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode:  'development',
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/js/main.js','./src/scss/style.scss'],
    admin: ['./src/js/admin.js', './src/scss/admin.scss']

  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function () {
                return [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'assets/img/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "/css/[name].css",
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      {from: './src/img', to: 'img'},
      {from: './src/icon', to: 'icon'},
      {from: './src/fonts', to: 'fonts'},
    ]),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 9000
  },
};
```

when i run `npm run build` i see the files in there correct subdirectories
i.e.

```
/dist/css/app.css
/dist/css/admin.css
/dist/js/app.bundle.js
/dist/js/admin.bundle.js
```

If I take the `CleanWebpackPlugin()`  out run `npm run build` then `npm start` the file is served, but I do not understand why it can not serve this when it runs in memory.

It also works make the following change

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "/css/[name].css",  Remove this
      filename: "[name].css"  Add this
    }),
```

However then I do not get the subdirectory structure I want.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like everything i had is ok i just needed to remove the `/`

eg

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "/css/[name].css",  replace this line
      filename: "css/[name].css"  with this line
    }),
```